# How is splitting done on numerical predictors in randomForest package in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

I understand that for the individual trees, a least squares measure is used to measure node impurity, given candidate splits of the data at that split, and the best split is selected.

What I don't understand yet (since I couldn't find an answer in the documentation) is how candidate splits are found in the first place, i.e., given *numerical* predictors (not nominal or ordinal), how are the split points found for those numerical predictors in the randomForest package?

Aside: I am also wondering whether ordinal predictors and dependent variables are supported in randomForest now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same as with ordinal variables -- the algorithm goes from the minimal to a maximal value present in the attributes as a candidate for a threshold and selects best. This can be elegantly speed-up to linear complexity using presorting.

Because of that randomForest simply converts ordered factors to numerical values for predictors and to categorical data in case of decision.